# Short glitch sound when skipping to next song

Tags: music, speakers

I have a Macbook M1 Pro 2021 with Monterey. Sometimes, when I skip to the next song, a short glitch sound comes from the speaker. It doesn't happen always. It happens sporadically. I couldn't find the exact steps to reproduce the issue.

It occurs with Youtube Music, Spotify, and VLC. It occurs mostly when I use the keyboard shortcut for skipping to next song. Sometimes it occurs when I skip to the next song by clicking Next button in the corresponding app as well. But this is less frequent.

Any idea about the reason of this issue?

Comment: What type of speakers do you have?  How are they connected?  What does the glitch sound like?

Comment: I use built-in speakers of macbook. The sound is some random noise sound that lasts less than 1 second.

Comment: An actual sound like from a sound file, a screech, a squelch, a click, a buzz….. “Random sound” is too vague a descriptor.  Also, please post updates with an [edit] to the original question.

Comment: Does it happen if you use headphones?  What about a Bluetooth or USB audio device?